# How to translate SQL Server stored procedure into Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, plsql

This is my SQL Server stored procedure which is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE flight_details
AS
BEGIN 
SELECT Airline.Airline_No, Airline_Name, Airplane.Airplane_No, Airplane_Name, Flight.Flight_No, Flight_Type, City_Departure, City_Transit, City_Arrival, Departure_Date_Time, Transit_Date_Time, Arrival_Date_Time, Flight_Duration_in_hours, Transit_Duration_in_hours, Flight_Status
FROM Airline,Airplane, Flight
WHERE Airline.Airline_No = Airplane.Airline_No AND Airline.Airline_No=Flight.Airline_No AND Airplane.Airplane_No=Flight.Airplane_No
END

EXECUTE flight_details
```

The above SQL Server stored procedure worked successfully.

Next, I tried to translate it into Oracle stored procedure code which is shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE flight_details
(p_flight_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS 
BEGIN 
OPEN p_flight_details FOR
SELECT Airline.Airline_No, Airline_Name, Airplane.Airplane_No, Airplane_Name, Flight.Flight_No, Flight_Type, City_Departure, City_Transit, City_Arrival, Departure_Date_Time, Transit_Date_Time, Arrival_Date_Time, Flight_Duration_in_hours, Transit_Duration_in_hours, Flight_Status
FROM Airline,Airplane, Flight
WHERE Airline.Airline_No = Airplane.Airline_No AND Airline.Airline_No=Flight.Airline_No AND Airplane.Airplane_No=Flight.Airplane_No
END flight_details;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

EXECUTE flight_details;
```

I tried creating this procedure in Oracle SQL Developer but it was showing the following error:

```
Error(5,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(7,133): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Error(8,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query    json_object json_array
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you can access the following link and convert your block code from SQL to Oracle.

http://sqlines.com/online

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon at the end of your cursor's select statement.

```
WHERE Airline.Airline_No = Airplane.Airline_No AND Airline.Airline_No=Flight.Airline_No AND Airplane.Airplane_No=Flight.Airplane_No;
```